# Lua socket client:send function

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua, httprequest, http-1.0

I am making an effort to understand sockets in lua. I am a bit stuck in client:send(data [, i [, j]]) as http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#send provides but I can't quite understand what it actually does and this manual doesn't explain much. For example, in order to send a file request, we use c:send("GET " .. file .. " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"). Why should we use "GET" at the start and "HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" at the end? I've searched for other sites but none seem to be informative enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all explained in the [HTTP 1.0 protocol specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html).

Read specially [the request section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Request) of the specs:

> The `Request-Line` begins with a method token, followed by the
>   `Request-URI` and the protocol version, and ending with `CRLF`. The
>   elements are separated by `SP` characters. No `CR` or `LF` are allowed
>   except in the final `CRLF` sequence.
>
> ```
> Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
> ```

There are the [following methods supported](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Methods):

- GET
- POST
- HEAD

SP is separator. CRLF is CR (carriage return) followed by LF (newline feed) characters. The constants are [listed here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Basic-Rules).

So, in a request formed like below:

```
GET some/path/to/file.lua HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

You have:

- Method = `GET`
- URI = `some/path/to/file.lua`
- HTTP version = `HTTP/1.0`
- CR = `\r`
- LF = `\n`

The characters `\r` and `\n` respectively represent CR and LF in several programming languages. The are actually the same characters as: `string.char(13)` and `string.char(10)` respectively.